# How do you find the expectation of a product of Ito integrals with domains that do not overlap?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am looking at the following expectation:

$\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{s}G(s')dW(s')\int_{s}^{t}H(t')dW(t')]$

Intuitively I think the expectation should be zero since the domain of the two integrals do not overlap. However, I am not sure how to show this. I was thinking I could rewrite the integral as a sum and then find the result, but I seem to get lost in the algebra. Any ideas?

Comment: *Hint.* Write the expectation as $$\mathbb{E}\biggl[\biggl(\int_{0}^{t}G(u)\mathbf{1}_{[0,s]}(u) \,\mathrm{d}W(u)\biggr)\biggl(\int_{0}^{t}H(u)\mathbf{1}_{[s,t]}(u) \,\mathrm{d}W(u)\biggr)\biggr]$$ and then apply the [Itô isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry).

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!